# How can I use local variables in gitlab pages

Tags: gitlab

I made a react app and host it in gitlab pages (`groupname.gitlab.io/repo`). But I want no one else to see it. so I thought if I have a variable on my local browser storage I could check if the value of the local variable matches the gitlab pages private variable and if so load the app.

Does gitlab does have a variables section in **CI / CD Settings** but not sure if those can be used in the pages and how.

Or is there any other free service that provides private variables.

And would this be private enough for simple demo work

```
function Greeting(props) {
  const isLoggedIn = browserVarriable === gitlabVariable;
  if (isLoggedIn) {
    return <AppComponent />;
  }
  return <ErrorComponent />;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [GitLab Pages Access Control](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/introduction.html#gitlab-pages-access-control-core-only) to protect your Pages site? The documentation explains how to set it up. Then, your site would be restricted to people who have access to your project within GitLab. Note that this is not yet available on GitLab.com (see the note at the top of the docs section).

To answer your actual question, GitLab CI/CD secret variables are not directly passed to Pages sites. Pages sites are completely standalone deployed static sites. GitLab CI only builds and deploys the static files. However, you could use a secret variable and then write that variable somewhere within your site files during the CI build process. The value would then be deployed with the site. I'm not sure how secure that would be, though.

Comment: The access control would be better but I don't know how to do it. Where would [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/pages/index.html#access-control), I created this `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` in the root of the project but didn't work?

Comment: Are you hosting your page on GitLab.com? If so, it's not yet available. The `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` bit would be pertinent if you hosted your own GitLab instance on your own server/VM.